# Pipeline - Parameterised Trigger Plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a **pipeline** type job in my Jenkins. What I am trying to do is to run some pipelines with a parameter like release. For example, I want to run this pipeline for version `1.3.5`. I prepared a pipeline code for that and tried to use [`Parameterized Trigger Plugin`](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) to make it parameterised. This plugin was working for normal type tasks but, I couldn't make it works with pipelines.

Here is my definition of the variable;

[image]

I can't access the variable I defined with the plugin. Here is the **pipeline** part which tries to access it;

```
....
build_tag = "${TAG}"
```

[image]

But, `build_tag` variable is always `null`. I tried `env.${TAG}` and `${env.TAG}` but no result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I defined String param named THIS_IS_TEST and was able to get the value with -

```
echo "${THIS_IS_TEST}"
```

Make sure that the plugin is updated

Comment: I was using the old version of pipeline plugins. It was not about Parameterized Trigger plugin by the way. Updating update all of them solved it, Thank you.